# React-Native-Web configuration issue: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-screens'

Tags: react-native, babeljs, react-native-web

I'm trying to render a react native app for web using react-native-web, babel, and webpack.
When I start webpack, I get the error below.
As you can see from my web.config.js, I'm included the react native modules I need for rendering the custom react native code. 
The react-native-screens module is installed, as you can see from the package.json.

My question why the compiler is complaining about the react-native-screens dependency in the node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/StackView/StackViewCard.js if that module is installed?

Any pointers appreciated.

**error:**
    ERROR in ./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/StackView/StackViewCard.js
    Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'react-native-screens' in '~/ReactNative/RNProto1/node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/StackView'
     @ ./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/views/StackView/StackViewCard.js 1:931-962
     @ ./node_modules/react-navigation-stack/dist/index.js
     @ ./node_modules/react-navigation/src/react-navigation.js
     @ ./mydemo/demo.js
     @ ./index.web.js

**babel.config.js:**

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ["@babel/env", "module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"],
  plugins: []
};
```

**package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "react-native-demo",
  "dependencies": {
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.8.5",
    "lodash": "^4",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "2.5.6",
    "react-native-screens": "^1.0.0-alpha.23",
    "react-native-svg": "9.8.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.8.3",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.8.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.4.3",
    "@commitlint/cli": "^7.1.1",
    "@commitlint/config-conventional": "^7.1.1",
    "@semantic-release/changelog": "^2.0.2",
    "@semantic-release/git": "^5.0.0",
    "acorn": "6.3.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^24.7.1",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
    "babel-plugin-react-docgen": "^3.2.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.11",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.3",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.92.0",
    "glob": "^7.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
    "husky": "^0.14.3",
    "image-size": "^0.6.2",
    "imagemin": "^5.3.1",
    "jest": "^24.7.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.56.4",
    "mkdirp": "^0.5.1",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.1.2",
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-art": "^16.12.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.12.0",
    "react-native": "^0.59.4",
    "react-native-web": "^0.11.7",
    "react-navigation": "^2.18.3",
    "react-styleguidist": "^10.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.8.3",
    "semantic-release": "^15.4.1",
    "standard": "^12.0.1",
    "style-loader": "0.23.1",
    "svgexport": "^0.3.2",
    "url-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "webpack": "^4.41.5",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.10",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.1",
    "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1 || 16.4.1 || 16.8.3 || 16.8.6",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4 || ^0.56.0 || ^0.59.0 || ^0.60.5"
  }
}
```

**web.config.js:**

```
const fs = require('fs');
const isDev = true;
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
module.exports = {
  entry: './index.web.js',
  output: {
      path: path.join(__dirname, '/web'),
      filename: "bundle.js",
      publicPath: '/'
  },
  devServer: {
      inline: false,
      contentBase: path.join(__dirname, '/web'),
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      'react-native': 'react-native-web'
    },
    // Resolve to iOS-specific components
    extensions: ['.ios.js', '.android.js', '.js', '.json']
  },
  target: 'node', // in order to ignore built-in modules like path, fs, etc. 
  module: {
    rules: [
      // Babel loader config
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        include: [
          path.join(__dirname, '/index.web.js'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/app'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/demo'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/src'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-dismiss-keyboard'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-drawer-layout'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-drawer-layout-polyfill'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-linear-gradient'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-safe-area-view'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-screens'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-svg'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-native-tab-view'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-navigation'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-navigation-deprecated-tab-navigator'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-navigation-drawer'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-navigation-stack'),
          path.join(__dirname, '/node_modules/react-navigation-tabs')
        ],
        options: {
          plugins: [
          ],
          presets: ['@babel/env', 'module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
          babelrc: false
        }  
      },
      // Image loader config
      {
        test: /\.(gif|jpe?g|png|svg)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            name: '[name].[ext]'
          }
        }
      }, 
      // CSS loader config
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

Comment: Did you resolve this error? This very important for me.

Comment: Any updates herE?

Answer (score 0):

Have you done this is Command Prompt or the Terminal :

```
    npm install react-native-screens
    yarn add react-native-screens
```

[Here is an Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXrSH.png)